# Laravel Eloquent Batch Insert or Update

Tags: php, csv, laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing a class to handle importing data from CSV files into the local database. The purpose is to pull in email send reports from our email platform and update our local database with the newest status for each email for a given campaign.

I'm currently parsing the CSV line by line and pushing each line into the function below.

```
private function intoDB($id,$data,$schema,$chunk = 500) {

    if(!isset($this->emails)) {
        $this->emails = [];
    }

    $email = [];

    foreach($schema as $key => $value) {
        $email[$value] = $data[$key];
    }

    $email['created_at'] = new \DateTime;
    $email['updated_at'] = $email['created_at'];        

    $this->emails[] = $email;

    if(count($this->emails) > $chunk) {
        \Email::insert($this->emails);
        $this->emails = [];
    }
}
```

The `$schema` variable matched CSV columns to table fields and looks like this:

```
    $schema = [
        1 => 'campign_id',
        2 => 'email'

    ];
```

This works really well for inseting new data that the table has never seen before, howver I would like to update a row if the same combination of campaign_id and email are already there. I know of `firstOrNew()` but that yeilds the following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `emails` where (`0` = 59 and `1` = xxx@xxx.com
```

I assume this is because I'm not creating models until I have it save the data (it's too slow to save them one by one)

Any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get `$data` in your class?

Comment: `$csv = new CSVReader();
   $csv->lineByLine($file,function($data)     use($id,$schema) {
    $this->intoDB($id,$data,$schema);
   },1);`

the lineByLine function of CSVReader calls the closure for each line of the CSV file and passes the line as $data.

Comment: Can't you just remove the duplicates before you insert them into `DB` ?

Comment: update-or-insert is much much slower than removing duplicates from the data, treating them separately and just inserting the other data... But anyway, how are you calling `firstOrNew` (and would you want `firstOrCreate` instead? `firstOrNew` creates a new instance and **doesn't** save it ) ? are you calling it with only **ONE** `$email` instead of chunks?

Comment: @TheAlpha Yeah, this ended up being the best option. I just clear out everything with the given campaign id before inserting the new data. Thanks.